# Real Analysis: open and closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Show that every open set A in a metric space (X,d) is the union of closed sets.

I am beyond confused for this question. I thought union of closed sets are closed

Comment: whichever answer you accept, you should note that _any_ subset of a metric space is the union of closed sets (namely, singletons).

Answer (score 2):

*Finite unions* of closed sets are indeed closed.

**Hint:** Construct an open ball around a point as a union of (increasing) closed balls around the same point. Then notice that every open set is a union of open balls.

Comment: Hi, i am new to this,so please forgive my ignorance. Would the radius of the open ball be also increasing with each successive closed ball? I'm a little confused obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Every set is a union of the points in it.  Since points are closed, arbitrary unions of closed sets can fail to be closed.

So as stated, every open set is a union of closed sets, since its a union of the points.  What makes it interesting is the restriction to showing that an open set set is a *countable* union of closed sets, which is harder.  Berci's answer explains how to prove this harder result.

Comment: I’ve upvoted, but properly speaking points aren’t closed: **singletons** — sets containing just a single point — are closed in metric space. (Note that this isn’t true of topological spaces in general, but then neither is the result in question.) Similarly, a set isn’t the union of the points in it; it’s the union of the singletons of those points.

Comment: I debated about thought about being more precise in the exact way you point out, but I wasn't sure if it would help john doe or not.

Comment: That’s a legitimate consideration, but one can do both. First give the informal statement, since (a) it’s simple and will almost certainly be understood, and (b) it’s perfectly true that people do say such things. (Even I occasionally do, and I’m a lot fussier in that respect than most mathematicians of my acquaintance.) Then at the end add a note similar to my comment explaining why the original statement is technically incorrect and what one would say if one were being careful and strictly accurate.

Comment: That's a good point.

Comment: @arsmath : it is not obvious to me how Berci's answer explains how to prove "this harder result", especially if your metric space is something wacky/nonseparable/etc.  Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @arsmath : your answer is correct, but I think it is worth it to show the OP that your argument shows _every_ set in a metric space is a union of closed sets.

Answer (score 0):

Any singleton (a set containing one point) is a closed subset of the metric space.  So *any* subset of a metric space (not necessary an open set, closed set, etc.) is a union of closed sets.  It is true that an infinite union of closed sets is not necessarily closed, but that wasn't the question you asked.