# Every open set as union of closed sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that every open set can be written as a union of closed sets. I really have no idea where to start with this proof, does anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you think that's possible?

Comment: In what topological space?

Comment: A better question would be countable union of closed sets

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497811/real-analysis-open-and-closed-sets see this

Answer (score 1):

As you use the tag "metric spaces" we can assume we are in a metric space. But then the statement is quite trivial, as all sets of the form $\{x\}, x \in X$ are closed, and we can write any set $A$ as $\cup \{\{x\}: x \in A \}$. So nothing about openness and almost nothing of the metric is then used.

It is true that every open set in a metric is the countable union of closed sets(we cannot expect finte, as a finite union of closed sets is closed and many metric spaces have open sets that are not closed).

Sketch of proof: define $d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a): a \in A\}$ for any non-empty set $A$. Then if $O$ is open (and wlog unequal to $X$) we can write $O = \cup F_n$, where $F_n = \{x : d(x,X \setminus O) \le \frac{1}{n}\}$. Using that $d(x,A)$ is a continuous function (for fixed $A$) on $X$, one sees the $F_n$ are closed, and openness of $O$ is used to show that the union holds.